# Body height not expanding with mat-card

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, angular-material

I am having a issue with a mat-card on my webpage. The problem is the bottom of the mat-card looks cutoff at the bottom of the webpage. I believe this is caused by the body height of the web page not expanding to contain the mat-card. Looks like this:
[image]

[image]

The code is as follows:

**HTML for Products View Component**

```
<div class="view">
<h3 class="mainText">Products</h3>
<div class="row">
  <div class="itemRow" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutWrap fxLayoutGap="10px" fxLayoutAlign="center">
    <app-view-product-card *ngFor="let product of newestProducts" [product]="product" style="margin-bottom: none;"></app-view-product-card>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**SCSS for Products View Component**

```
html,
 body {
 height: 100%;
 }

.view{
  .row{
    margin-left: 2vw;
    margin-top: 4vh;
  }

  app-view-product-card{
    width: 25vw;
    height: 70vh;
  }
}


mat-button-toggle-group {
  margin-left: 8vw;
}
```

**HTML for Product Card Component**

```
<mat-card class="productCard" appMaterialElevation defaultElevation="2" raisedElevation="16">
  <mat-card-header>
    <ngx-avatar mat-card-avatar class="my-avatar" src={{product.authorProfile}} *ngIf="product.authorProfile != ''" class="avatar-header" size="40"> </ngx-avatar>
    <mat-card-title>{{product.title}}</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle>{{product.author}}</mat-card-subtitle>
  </mat-card-header>
  <img mat-card-image [src]="product.imageLinks ? product.imageLinks[0] : null" alt="Photo" class="cardImage">
</mat-card>
```

**SCSS for Product Card Component**

```
.productCard{
  height: 68%;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  margin-right: 2rem;
  min-width: 20%;


  .cardImage{
    width: 100%;
    height: 35vh;
    margin:auto;
  }
}

.productTile{
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: make `height and margin to px, not in % or vh or rem` and the picture you link is more confusing, please post a complete screenshot.

Comment: @PrabeshGouli Thanks for the response! I added the screenshot.